# Can I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu without problems using Software Updater?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, update-manager

I'm new to Ubuntu. Can I use this window for upgrading but without any problems?

Does the update process delete or change other applications I'm using?

[image: Software Updater window]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can upgrade without any problem as long as you're upgrading from LTS version to LTS. LTS stands for Long Term Support. When you'll upgrade, your applications won't be removed but it's worth nothing,
your official Ubuntu repositories will be upgraded to new repositories. Because repositories for different versions of Ubuntu are managed separately. And all the third party repositories you might be using will be disabled. You can re-enable them after upgrade.